# Why doesn't code lens reflect tests run after an ordered test execution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Why doesn't code lens reflect tests run after an ordered test execution?

I can run them individually and code lens is immediately updated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added all the tests to a playlist and code lens reflecting correctly, hooray!